# Create a Ruby object with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
  has_many :topics, :through => :contents
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
  has_many :courses, :through => :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :courses
  belongs_to :topics
end
```

If I want to create a course and topic on the spot, I would do:

```
t1 = Topic.create(name: "Topic 1")
t2 = Topic.create(name: "Topic 1")
Course.create(name: "Course 1", topics: [t1, t2])
```

That would create the `Content` record automatically. If I add an additional column to `Content`, say `my_column`, is there a way to create my course as quickly, including the new `Content` column?

Something along the lines of:

```
Course.create(name: "Course 1", topics: [(t1, my_column: 1), (t2, my_column: 2)])
```

Comment: [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoshBrody Can you ELI5 it to me on this example case? I'm having a little trouble applying the concept on this context

Comment: @JoshBrody's comment above and answer below are indeed the correct ways to implement what you need.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Content is a table to handle the many-to-many relationship between Course and Topic. When I do Course.create and pass along that array of topics, it IS creating the proper records on the database in the Content table (I'm testing it right now). None of your answers resolve my problem, or at least I don't see how yet

Answer (score 3):

[ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is what you're looking for.

From the docs,

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent. By default nested attribute updating is turned off and you can enable it using the #accepts_nested_attributes_for class method. When you enable nested attributes an attribute writer is defined on the model.

I can't test it right now, but you'll end up doing something like,

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents
    has_many :topics, :through => :contents
    accepts_nested_attribute_for :topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents
    has_many :courses, :through => :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :courses
    belongs_to :topics
end


t1 = Topic.create(name: "Topic 1")
t2 = Topic.create(name: "Topic 1")
course = Course.new(name: "Course 1")
course.topics << t1
course.topics << t2

course.save!

puts course.topics # ... t1, t2
```

There's a lot more you can do, including creating new child records on the parent on the fly as well. The docs — and StackOverflow — are riddled with more documentation on it :)

Comment: I don't think you understood very well my question. It is about the extra column on the "Content" table. I don't know how to fill it when creating Topics and Courses, other than running a query after creating the previous 2.

Comment: Yeah that's what `accepts_nested_attributes_for` permits. There's a million questions and answers about this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320284/edit-associated-model-by-input-form/44320724#44320724 for an example of what your controller will look like.